# Getting the top 5 call durations for each phone extention in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, subquery

|--------------------------------------------------------------|

 |  ID.             EXT   phneNumber         duration    |

 |--------------------------------------------------------------|

 | 78172       101   2233379092         00:00:23.0 |

 | 78175       104   2233818185         00:08:15.0 |

 | 78176       101   9339444840         00:04:56.0 |

 | 78177       108   2581594433         00:01:28.0 |

 | 78179       104   2533815944         00:02:30.0 |

 | 78180       101   2335343977         00:00:00.0 |

 | 78181       101   2335343977         00:01:36.0 |

 | 78186       108   9229661175         00:00:53.0 |

 | 78193       104   2538633408         00:00:00.0 |

 | 78194       108   2580013364         00:00:11.0 |

 | 78196       104   2583300164         00:00:16.0 |

 | 78197       104   9963341189         00:02:44.0 |

 | 78198       101   9663319313         00:03:58.0 |

 | 78199       101   2104834340         00:03:19.0 |

 | 78205       104   2222020401         00:00:00.0 |

 |--------------------------------------------------------------|

The table above shows a part of the data in a microsoft Access 2007 database.

EXT is the extension of a phone

phneNumber is the number that was called from that extention 

duration is the amount of time that the called lasted

I need to write a query to find the 5 Longest(in duration) calls per extention. The desired result is showed below

|--------------------------------------------------------------|

 |  ID.             EXT   phneNumber         duration    |

 |--------------------------------------------------------------|

 | 78176       101   9339444840         00:04:56.0 |

 | 78198       101   9663319313         00:03:58.0 |

 | 78199       101   2104834340         00:03:19.0 |

 | 78181       101   2335343977         00:01:36.0 |

 | 78172       101   2233379092         00:00:23.0 |

 | 78175       104   2233818185         00:08:15.0 |

 | 78197       104   9963341189         00:02:44.0 |

 | 78179       104   2533815944         00:02:30.0 |

 | 78196       104   2583300164         00:00:16.0 |

 | 78193       104   2538633408         00:00:00.0 |

 | 78177       108   2581594433         00:01:28.0 |

 | 78186       108   9229661175         00:00:53.0 |

 | 78194       108   2580013364         00:00:11.0 |

 |--------------------------------------------------------------|

I tried the below query but is not working as desired and it's very slow as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ext, phneNumber, duration FROM transactions) t
WHERE t.duration IN ( SELECT TOP 5 duration 
                       FROM   transactions
                       WHERE  t.ext = ext
                       ORDER  BY duration desc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't see why you are using `distinct` in the outer `from` clause.  See if this does what you want:

```
SELECT ext, phneNumber, duration
FROM transactions as t
WHERE t.duration IN ( SELECT TOP 5 t2.duration 
                       FROM   transactions t2
                       WHERE  t.ext = t2.ext
                       ORDER  BY t2.duration desc);
```

`TOP` in MS Access works differently from `top` in SQL Server and Sybase, because it returns duplicates.  That is, it can return more than five rows if there are duplicates.

If that is an issue, you might try:

```
SELECT ext, phneNumber, duration
FROM transactions as t
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT TOP 5 t2.id
               FROM transactions t2
               WHERE t.ext = t2.ext
               ORDER BY t2.duration desc, t2.id
              );
```

Comment: The 1st one indeed produces many duplicates whilst the second take forever to run

Comment: @javasuns . . . I'm surprised at that.  An index on `transactions(ext, duration, id)` should actually help both queries.

Comment: 2nd Query has finished now and still more than 5 results (same as 1)

Comment: We are talking about 137045 rows

Comment: @javasuns . . . I think the second query requires an `id` in the `order by` clause to get exactly 5.

Comment: Gordon thanks for all your help but I still have two problems.
First with your 2nd query the duration is not returned in descending order.
Second the query is too slow even after the creation of indexes

Comment: You can download the database I am currently working on from the following link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/spza3zon0j2tbvg/Pabx2003.mdb?dl=0

Here is the query I am running
SELECT ext,number_dialed, duration
FROM   transactions t
WHERE  t.aa IN ( SELECT TOP 5 aa 
                 FROM   transactions
                 WHERE  t.ext = ext
                 ORDER  BY duration desc,aa);

The numbers are replaced with xxxxxxxx for obvious reasons. Thanks

Comment: @javasuns . . . If you want the results from the query ordered, then you need to add an `order by` to the outer query.

Comment: Yes I managed to do that. Is there anyway to make it run faster? I mean it takes up to 30mins to bring the results

Comment: @javasuns . . . If you switch to another database engine (such as a free version of SQL Server), you will probably find that it runs faster.  Apart from the index mentioned above, I can't think of any other ideas for MS Access.